# Rewrite URL for over 300,000 different hotels

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know this question has been asked in many places but what I am trying to achieve is a little different.

Scenario:

I have a /hotel/index.php page that pulls up hotel data from a MySQL database with the variable "id".

What I want to achieve is for example /hotel/index.php?id=1 should display as /hotel/hotelname/

Here is what my index.php looks like:

```
 <?php

 $dbhost = something;
 $dbuser = somethingmore;
 $dbpass = alotmore;
 $hid = $_GET["id"];

 $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
 if(! $conn )
 {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM hotel where id = .$hid';

 mysql_select_db('h_db');
 $retval = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hotel WHERE id='". mysql_real_escape_string( $hid ) ."'", >$conn );

 if(! $retval )
 {
   die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
 }
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
 {

    if($row['inventory_source']="T") // Check inventory source
  {
 $hotelid = $row['hotelid_t'];
  }
  else
  {
 $hotelid = $row['hotelid_b'];
  }
         $hotelname = $row['hotel_name'];
         $thumbnail = $row['thumbnail'];
         $hoteladdress = $row['hotel_address_full'];
         $cityname = $row['city'];
         $cityid = $row['cityid'];
         $country = $row['country_name'];
         $propertydesc = $row['property_description'];
         $amenities = $row['xmlamenities'];
         $checkin = $row['checkin'];
         $checkout = $row['checkout'];
         $petsallowed = $row['pets_allowed'];
         $guestrating = $row['overall_rating'];
         $star = $row['star_rating'];
         $roomcount = $row['room_count'];

 }
```

I know this can be achieved using mod_rewrite. But I don't know how to do it. Any help from the pros out there will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check this out http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/

Answer (score 0):

make ".htaccess" file and put this code to it:

```
IndexIgnore *
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^hotel\/([^\\/]*)$ /hotel/index.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

and in index.php you should search mysql table by hotel name.

```
$retval = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hotel WHERE hotel_name='". mysql_real_escape_string( $id ) ."'", >$conn );
```

Comment: How would the htaccess file know the name that corresponds to the id?

Comment: my post edited when you type your comment.  you should search mysql table by hotel name.

Comment: No. If you got to `/index.php?id=17`, you want to redirect to `/hotel/verynicehotel`. Your htaccess will not do this.

Comment: we want "/hotel/index.php?id=1 display as /hotel/hotelname/". it means when user type /hotel/hotelname/ in browser, this address run in background: /hotel/index.php?id=1. old addresses are active now. we want to active new addresses.

Comment: This is just not what happens here. Your redirect puts the hotelname in the `id` parameter, so it's not an `id` parameter anymore, and all the old links will not work: why redirect at all to the old page, and not to a new page that works on hotelname? No, this is not the way to go

Comment: this is not the main question. we can use another variable for hotel name. index.php?name=$1 and edit php code for handle two parameter. id and name. but main question is that how redirect /hotel/abc to index.php

Comment: That's where we disagree. I read `/hotel/index.php?id=1 should display as /hotel/hotelname/`, meaning that going to that first url should point you to the second. Which this doesn't. You read something else. Good for you, no sense in discussing it more.

Comment: Ashkan thank you for your response. This is somewhere to start off with, but now to search a hotel it has to (index.php?hotel_name=blahblah) Right?
That is not workable because most hotels name has spaces between them and are very long. For example:
Days Inn Queensbury
@AshkanArefi

Comment: And lets say we do work the hotel name. What is the best way to use the variables in the url. Specially to truncate the spaces.
For example: hotel/index.php?hname=Days%Inn%Queensbury
points to: hotel/Days%inn%Queensbury

Comment: you can make a function to convert hotel name to a standard url. for example replace all spaces by dash & make it to lower case. also you can add a column in hotels table in database and use hotel standard username (hotel nickname) for them. for example "Green Hotel" > "green-hotel" & ... you should check these new names for duplicate titles & ... (all of these job can run in a function to upgrade your database for new address system). please see this address: http://www.studyco.com/profile/ashkan It use same htaccess and index.php & profile table with Staff full name & staff nick name.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

First, you can probably figure out how to detect if you need to redirect. If you've done that:

```
 //$indexpage = this is an index.php?id=?? page
 if($indexpage){
    //insert your "find hotelname code"
    $hotelname = $row['hotel_name'];
    //make sure NO output is above this line!
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
    header("Location: http://www.yoursite.com/hotel/{$hotelname}"); 
  }else{
     //not an index page, so a hotel/hotelname page? (room for other pages here)
     //add code to find the hotel and show stuff. here. basically, your old page.
  }
```

The fun part is that your old pages will be redirected, but your real urls will be the new pages, so you can just call those / link those :)